# C : Infinite loop when using scanf

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I am using following structure:

```
struct Transistor {
   char  type_number[50];
   char  supplier[50];
   int   maxVce;
   float   maxIc;
   int   max_power;
   int   max_freq;
   int   max_gain;
   float   price;
};
```

Running code:

```
while(1==1){
        printf("Insert parameters: \n");
        char input[100];
        scanf ("%[^\n]", &input);
        char *token = strtok(input, " ");
        if(input[0]=='q'){
            return 0;
        }
        parameters[0]=atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        ic=atof(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        parameters[1]=atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        parameters[2]=atoi (token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        parameters[3]=atoi(token);


        printf ("\n Parameters: \nVCe:%d,\nPow:%d,\nFreq:%d,\nGain:%d \nIce:%.3f\n",parameters[0],parameters[1],parameters[2],parameters[3],ic);
        printf("Transistor that matches your requirements: \n");
        for(a=0; a<15; a++){
            i=0;
            if(parameters[0]<=all_Transistors[a].maxVce){
                i++;
            }
            if(parameters[1]<=all_Transistors[a].max_power){
                i++;
            }
            if(parameters[2]<=all_Transistors[a].max_freq){
                i++;
            }
            if(parameters[3]<=all_Transistors[a].max_gain){
                i++;
            }
            if(ic<=all_Transistors[a].maxIc) {
                i++;
            }
            if(i==5){
                printf("\n\nTransistor name: %s\n",all_Transistors[a].type_number);
                printf("Supplier: %s\n",all_Transistors[a].supplier);
                printf("Maximum Vce: %d\n",all_Transistors[a].maxVce);
                printf("Maximum Ic: %.3f\n",all_Transistors[a].maxIc);
                printf("Maximum power: %d\n",all_Transistors[a].max_power);
                printf("Maximum freq: %d\n",all_Transistors[a].max_freq);
                printf("Maximum gain: %d\n",all_Transistors[a].max_gain);
                printf("Price: %.3f\n",all_Transistors[a].price);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thing is:
I am entering the first set of parameters like:

```
1 1.1 2 3 4
```

It works fine loop runs again but `scanf` is not, it should work as long as user enters `q` as a first character of input.

Why is `scanf` not running every loop?

Comment: You don't need the `&` in `scanf ("%[^\n]", &input);`

Comment: @user3121023 thanks, it is working now ! :)

Comment: Small advive generally infinite loop are written as `while(1)` or `for(;;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem with this line:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]", &input);
```

was that it reads everything from the `stdin` buffer up to `'\n'` **and leaves `'\n'` in the buffer**. So the next time you get back to that line to read from the buffer, the first char in the buffer is still `'\n'` resulting in nothing being read and the buffer not being changed.

(Another problem with that line is that there is the risk of buffer overflow if the line being read is longer than the `input` array).

There is more than one way to fix this but the simplest one (that also should protect you from buffer overflow) would be the one that has been mentioned in the comments, by using `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);`.

Comment: The other simple way to fix it is to put a space at the beginning of the format string.

Comment: @Barmar You're right. Only problem with that fix is that you would need to do more to also protect you from buffer overflow.